# Facebook Android SDK warning: "Removal of Tokenless Access Point"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I received the following warning via email from Facebook Developers a few days ago:

> As part of our [Graph API 8.0 release](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/user/picture), we announced changes to how
> developers can access User Picture and FB/IG OEmbed endpoints. We are
> including more information about these changes below so you can make
> the appropriate updates to your apps.
>
> Facebook will now require client or app access tokens to access a
> user’s profile picture when querying against user IDs. Beginning on
> October 24, 2020, queries for profile pictures made against user IDs
> without an access token will return a generic silhouette rather than a
> profile picture. While client or app tokens will be required for user
> ID queries, they will continue to be a best practice (and not
> required) for ASID queries for the time being. You can read more about
> this change in our developer documentation for User Picture.

Going by the above message, I'm not sure whether my block of code will be affected. Here is the code:

```
val profilePicUrl = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(600, 600).toString()
```

That line gets the URI of the user's profile image **after they have logged in**.

Source code from the SDK:

```
/**
 * Getter for the profile that is currently logged in to the application.
 * @return The profile that is currently logged in to the application.
 */
public static Profile getCurrentProfile()
{
    return ProfileManager.getInstance().getCurrentProfile();
}

/**
 * Getter for the Uri of the profile picture.
 *
 * @param width  The desired width for the profile picture.
 * @param height The desired height for the profile picture.
 * @return The Uri of the profile picture.
 */
public Uri getProfilePictureUri(
        int width,
        int height) {
    return ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(this.id, width, height);
}

public static Uri getProfilePictureUri(
        String userId,
        int width,
        int height) {

    Validate.notNullOrEmpty(userId, "userId");

    width = Math.max(width, UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION);
    height = Math.max(height, UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION);

    if (width == UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION && height == UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Either width or height must be greater than 0");
    }

    Uri.Builder builder =
            Uri.parse(ServerProtocol.getGraphUrlBase())
                    .buildUpon()
                    .path(String.format(
                            Locale.US, PATH,
                            FacebookSdk.getGraphApiVersion(),
                            userId));

    if (height != UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION) {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(HEIGHT_PARAM, String.valueOf(height));
    }

    if (width != UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION) {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(WIDTH_PARAM, String.valueOf(width));
    }

    builder.appendQueryParameter(MIGRATION_PARAM, MIGRATION_VALUE);
```

I'm not sure whether I will be affected as I don't specifically use the `Graph API`?

Is someone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Of course you _are_ using the Graph API here. Just because you use an SDK that encapsulates the functionality, so that you don’t have to write requests on the HTTP level yourself, does not mean that the API was not involved. The important question here is, does this automatically pass the current access token with this particular request.

Comment: @04FS Yes your last sentence is mostly what I am curious about. As the user is already logged in I assumed the current access token is already incorporated into the function...

Comment: Well then dig deeper into the source, and see what `ImageRequest` does … At some point, this is probably going to use some generic request object or method, and by default the access token will probably get added there automatically, if not explicitly overwritten.

Comment: Added in edits above - it passes in `userId` but I can't see Access Token @04FS

Comment: I would not expect them to explicitly add the default access token all over the place, in every single method. But it could be, that `Uri.Builder` adds it, or something like that.